# how to understand "===(identity)" when using to compare two type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know that in Swift, `===` operator just like `==` in Objective-C when compare two classes, return true if two side variable points to same heap address

but I encounter a using case of `===` to compare two type

```
func typeTester(d:Dog, _ whattype:Dog.Type) {
    // if d.dynamicType is whattype { // compile error, "not a type" (i.e. a not a type literal)
    if d.dynamicType === whattype {
        print("yep")
    } else {
        print("nope")
    }
}
```

which I don't really understand, So, a type still have memory address?

Answer (score 1):

1) `whattype` is variable which stores type information.

2) `is` operator must be followed by certain type not variable which stores information about some type

> Use the type check operator `is` to check whether an instance is of a
>   certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if the
>   instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not.

3) `identity` operator used

> to check whether two constants or variables refer to the same single
>   instance

Which means that you are trying to mix different types checking techniques:

```
// incorrect
d.dynamicType is whattype
d.dynamicType == Dog
d.dynamicType === Dog
d == whattype

// technically correct, but logically not and will always return false
d.dynamicType is Dog // Xcode will show warning
d === whattype

// correct
d is Dog
d.dynamicType == whattype
d.dynamicType === whattype
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift has two types of values - value types (which are passed by value, using copies - structs, enums) and reference types (which are passed by reference - classes).

What is a reference? A reference is a memory address. And that's what `===` is comparing. It compares whether two object references point to the same object.

There are some classes which have singleton instances. That means that comparing instance references is safe and represents equality. Type references are one of the cases when comparing using `===` (identity) is safe. The runtime has an internal pool of type references and it always return the same instance for the same type.